# Cannot pass the list value to apigateway update-method, getting Invalid type for parameter patchOperations[2].value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to update the method `authorizationScopes` with the list value using the following command:

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxxx --resource-id yyyyy --http-method ANY \
--patch-operations "op=replace,path=/authorizationType,value=COGNITO_USER_POOLS" "op=replace,path=/authorizerId,value=zzzzz" \
"op=replace,path=/authorizationScopes,value=app-identifier/token,app-identifier/personProfile"
```

but got this error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter patchOperations[2].value, 
value: [u'app-identifier/token', u'app-identifier/personProfile'],
 type: <type 'list'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

Also try this command with `[]`:

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxxx --resource-id yyyyy --http-method ANY \
--patch-operations "op=replace,path=/authorizationType,value=COGNITO_USER_POOLS" "op=replace,path=/authorizerId,value=zzzzz" \
"op=replace,path=/authorizationScopes,value=[app-identifier/token,app-identifier/personProfile]"
```

but also getting the same error as above.

If I set it manually from the console and get it from this command:
`aws apigateway get-method --rest-api-id xxxxxxx --resource-id yyyy --http-method ANY`

give me this output:

```
{
    "apiKeyRequired": false,
    "httpMethod": "ANY",
    "methodIntegration": {
        "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
        "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
        "requestParameters": {},
        "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111:function:app:${stageVariables.ENV}/invocations",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "requestTemplates": {},
        "cacheNamespace": "xxxx",
        "type": "AWS_PROXY",
        "cacheKeyParameters": []
    },
    "authorizationScopes": [
        "app-identifier/token",
        "app-identifier/personProfile"
    ],
    "authorizationType": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "authorizerId": "yyyyy"
}
```

awscli limitation or I am passing it in wrong way

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-method.html

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of JSON syntax so I think you can resolve your issues in a simple manner. So, you can create a file called sample-update.json with the following content;

```
    {
        "restApiId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "resourceId": "yyyyy",
        "httpMethod": "ANY",
        "patchOperations": [
            {
                "op": "replace",
                "path": "/authorizationType",
                "value": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
                "from": "anything_you_like_or_ignore"
            },
            {
                "op": "replace",
                "path": "/authorizerId",
                "value": "zzzzz",
                "from": "anything_you_like2_or_ignore"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then execute line;

```
aws apigateway update-method --cli-input-json file://sample-update.json
```

I believe this is the to simplify your problem and to get on with another task :). Alternatively if you prefer not to use JSON you can run the following equivalent;

```
aws apigateway update-method \
    --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxxx \
    --resource-id yyyyy \
    --http-method ANY \
    --patch-operations \ 
    "op=replace,path=/authorizationType,value=COGNITO_USER_POOLS,from=anything" \ 
    "op=replace,path=/authorizerId,value=zzzzz,from=anything"
```

With regards to /authorizationScope, you can’t perform replace operations on them. I missed it first time answering your question.
See the [api gateway docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/method-update/)

Comment: same problem, it update the `authorizationType` but didn't update the `authorizationScopes`

Comment: I updated my answer and separated the scopes. Let us know whether that works.

Comment: No, still not working only `authorizationType` has been updated and not entertaining the `authorizationScopes`.

Comment: I updated my answer again and it is actually true that you can’t update those as it is not supported. See the docs I attached in the bottom of my answer. I know the docs point to REST API but it is certain that the same conditions and limitations would apply in case of AWS cli.

Comment: what's the difference my awscli command and the one that you have mentioned in the alternate solution. I think both are same.

Comment: I just added it in case you don't want to work with json files. It is nice to have it as part of the solution so that other people can just pick what they like.